# Do I use "went" or "had gone" here, and why?

Tags: tense, past-tense, past-perfect

I just got back home from a friend's house I **went** over to.

I just got back home from a friend's house I **had gone** over to.

Are both the above sentences grammatically correct?
What's the difference in their meaning?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate of another question.

Comment: Structurally it's no different to *I just bought the car I [**had**] wanted* - where I don't think anyone could say Past Perfect was "ungrammatical", but it's completely unnecessary and sounds clumsy. As ever, the advice is *Don't use Past Perfect unless you know you need it* - you'll still be wrong sometimes, but less often than if you try to use Past Perfect every time you think it's remotely credible.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I like your rule of thumb. The example you give about buying a car really hits home.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't see any grammatical misuse in either sentence, in common usage I think most people would just say "I just got back from a friend's house." Since you just got back from that house, there is no need to specify that you had previously gone to it.

If you say "I had gone over to a friend's house.", it sounds as if you are relating it as an event previous to something else that you will also talk about; "I had gone over to a friend's house, and he got a phone call telling him his sister had been in an accident." It's also grammatically correct to use the other construction here: "I went over to a friend's house, and he got a phone call...". But using "had gone over" without something else sounds strange.

Comment: I think @rcook makes a good point. A native speaker would say "I just got back from a friend's house". The extra words make it clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

Like the present perfect, which is (also) used to make a connection between the past and the present, with the past perfect it's expected to see some sort of link (this time in the past). Remember that **when it's clear from the context which event happened first, you can avoid using the past perfect** (like in this case, where it's obvious that you went before getting back).

So the present perfect would be useful to say that something, for example, happened *before* you got to your friend's house:

> I went to my friend's house, because I had bought a present for her.